# Spark Avoid hadoop fs.rename fail after writing a dataframe

Tags: azure, apache-spark, hadoop, rename, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to perform several fs.rename operations between directories after writing a dataframe on the first one:

```
val iPath = new Path(inputPath)
//Let's suppose a df has been written to iPath.
val tmpPath = new Path(oPath.toString + "_temporary")
val oPath = new Path(outputPath)
fs.rename(oPath, tmpPath)
fs.rename(iPath, oPath) //-> here it fails with a nullPointerException
fs.rename(tmpPath, iPath)
```

Why does it throw a nullPointerException on second step?

It seems that filesystem needs to wait until first rename is completed or something like that.

Comment: Can you share the NullPointerException stacktrace? Also what file system are you using?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$FolderRenamePending.execute(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:442)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.rename(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2426)
I'm using azure FS. As rename behaivour is to not delete the input folder until fs moves all files, I thought about implementing a do/while in each case to wait until input folder is deleted..but this is a weird implementation. Any ideas?

Comment: Update your question with Azure related details - FS used, scheme used etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'll believe it has to do with having not initialised your file system with a uri and possibly a config file. You might need to provide the following

```
val fs =new NativeAzureFileSystem()
fs.initialize(new URI ("wasbs://<containerName>@<storageAccount>.blob.core.windows.net/"),spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
```